# How to change value in list using basic operations?

Tags: python, arrays, list, math, python-3.x

Ok, I made myself the **challenge** so I can do some programming.

However I faced some **problems**.

```
adtprice = {19.99 , 49.99}
chldprice = adtprice * (3/4) - 7.5
```

And this is **Error** I got as the result.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Programming Scripts/park.py", line 2, in <module>
chldprice = adtprice * (3/4) - 7.5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'set' and 'float'
```

I wants it to be simple and useable since I will use adtprice and chldprice often.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You can't multiply a `set` with a number.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? BTW, Python sometimes understands our language ;) try to talk with it.

Comment: I wants chldprice to be other array that is {7.4925, 29.9925}

Comment: I used a `list` instead of a `set` but I get the same answer as you need. Refer to my answer below.

Comment: {7.4925, 29.9925} is not an `array`, it is [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). This is different.

Comment: @Bugboy1028 python version?

Comment: Python Verison is 3.2.3

Comment: @stalk, I didnt relazied that list used different operation. Thanks!

Comment: All of your answers are useful. However I had to choose one answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a set, not a list.  Use square brackets to create a list instead of curly braces.

As others have mentioned, you need to operate on individual elements of the list.

You can do so with a list comprehension

```
adtprice  = [19.99, 49.99]
chldprice = [p * (3./4) - 7.5
             for p in adtprice]
```

or using `map`, if you prefer:

```
adtprice  = [19.99, 49.99]
chldprice = map(lambda p: p * (3./4) - 7.5,
                adtprice)
```

If you find yourself wanting to do these types of bulk operations on sequences, consider using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).  It's a set of libraries that efficiently handle matrix and vector math in a concise and powerful way.  For example:

```
adtprice  = numpy.array([19.99, 49.99])
chldprice = adtprice * (3./4) - 7.5
```

Comment: Parentheses: (); Brackets: [], sometimes called "square brackets"; Braces: {}, sometimes called "curly braces" to emphasize the distinction; "Angle Brackets": <>, overloaded use of &lt; and &gt; entities or "less than" and "greater than" sigils.

In Python: () for tuples (and generator expressions), [] for lists (and list comprehensions), {} for dictionaries and sets (and for their generator expressions).

"Angled brackets" aren't used in Python's syntax (as such).

Comment: @JimDennis , I knows that but he is explaining 3 different ways to do it.

Comment: Just clarifying the accepted names for the various delimiter pairs and their usage in Python.  {} are NOT "angled" brackets.

Comment: @JimDennis is correct.  I mistyped when I said "angled brackets".  I meant curly braces.

Answer (score 4):

```
adtprice = [19.99 , 49.99]
chldprice = [a * (3.0/4) - 7.5 for a in adtprice]
```

Comment: +1. But you need to do `3.0/4` if you want me to keep my upvote.

Comment: Probably 3/4 is not the right way, as others said. Because 3/4 == 0. Must be smth like 3./4

Comment: No need of `3.0/4`, as OP is using py3.x.

Comment: @MarounMaroun there are better answers here, will delete in a minute

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you're looking for. First, a set can't be multiplied by a number, you can use list comprehension instead and `3/4` will just return `0` (Assuming Python 2.x). I'm assuming you want `3.0/4`.

```
>>> adtprice = [19.99 , 49.99]
>>> chldprice = [price*(3.0/4) - 7.5 for price in adtprice]
>>> chldprice
[7.4925, 29.9925]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to calculate the child price for each adult price. You don't have a list, but a set, so this should help:

```
adult_prices = [19.99, 49.99]
child_prices = []

for price in adult_prices:
    child_price = price * (3.0/4.0) - 7.5
    child_prices.append(child_price) # Add each child price to the array
    print("For adult price {}, child price is {}".format(price, child_price))

 print(adult_prices)
 print(child_prices)
```

Comment: Actually, This is not what I want, however it can be useful for other people.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers will work, if you want to actually do mathematical operations on sequences of values, I suggest using [the `numpy` library](http://www.numpy.org/). It does a really great job at exactly that. Here's what your code could look like using a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

adult_prices = np.asarray([19.99, 49.99])
child_prices = adult_prices * (3.0/4) - 7.5  # math operations work item by item

print(child_prices) # prints "array([  7.4925,  29.9925])"
```

There is a lot more you can do in a similar way. For instance, if you want only two digits after the decimal place, you can round the result:

```
child_prices = np.round(adult_prices * (3.0/4) - 7.5, 2)

print(child_prices) # prints "array([  7.49,  29.99])"
```

Comment: Does I need to download numpy?

Comment: @Bugboy1028: Yes, unfortunately numpy is not part of the Python standard library.